# I want to deform the mesh by script

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, sculpting

The log could not be seen in the sculpt mode deformed. So, it is partially deformed by the "sphere" of proportional editing.

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(4.95114, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='ENABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SPHERE', proportional_size=15.8631, release_confirm=True, use_accurate=False)
```

When I run this script, the selected part does not swell to a sphere, but the whole original model moves. I think it is happening because there is no part to specify the center point in the script. But I couldn't specify the center or other solutions.

What is the way to do proportional editing by script?Let me know if there are other ways you can do it in a script as well.For example,Is it possible to perform proportional editing by specifying Median?

[image: I want to do such an operation with a script.]

[image: This is the state after the operation.]